# JavaFX Exception in Application start method when executed with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, pom.xml

I have created a simple javaFX program and i added spring boot to javaFX by making the project a maven project. Before adding spring boot i got no error and the application worked fine.
I have provided the complete code below

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>RMI-DesktopClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  
</project>
```

AlarmsystemApplication.java

```
    @Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class AlarmSystemApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        this.applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(AlarmSystemApplication.class);

    }
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        applicationContext.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Login.loadView(stage);
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
  public class Login {
    public static void loadView(Stage stage) {

        try {
            Parent view = FXMLLoader.load(Login.class.getResource("../../../../../resources/com.ui.views/Login.fxml"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(view));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Login.fxml

```
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.alarmsystem.ui.views.Login">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="137.0" layoutY="157.0" text="Hello JavaFX">
         <font>
            <Font size="59.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**The error that i get**

```
    Exception in Application start method
2020-04-23 22:33:12.134  INFO 7228 --- [lication Thread] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-23 22:33:12.136  INFO 7228 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-23 22:33:12.139  INFO 7228 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at com.alarmsystem.ui.views.Login.loadView(Login.java:16)
    at com.alarmsystem.ui.AlarmSystemApplication.start(AlarmSystemApplication.java:34)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.alarmsystem.ui.AlarmSystemApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The file structure
[image]

The resources path
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is Spring related; the resource name you use for your FXML is not a valid resource name (and the stack trace indicates that not being able to find the FXML file is the issue).

Specifically, resource names cannot have `.` in them, so `..` and `com.ui.views` are both invalid.

So there are two problems here: one is that the resources name doesn't work with "parent directories" specified in it, and the other is that you have created a *folder* (not a *package*) under `resources` with illegal `.` characters in it. Also note that `resources` is a *source* folder, and is not available at runtime.

So, first, create a *package* under resources called `com.ui.views` and place the FMXL in there. I don't use IntelliJ, so I'm not sure if there is an option to do this, but if not you can create a folder `com`, a subfolder of it called `ui`, and a subfolder of that called `views`, and place the FXML file in `views`.

Then the correct resource name for the FXML, assuming you are using Maven defaults for your build, is

```
Parent view = FXMLLoader.load(Login.class.getResource("/com/ui/views/Login.fxml"));
```

If you restructure slightly so that the FXML file and `Login` class are in the same package (i.e. you make a `com.alarmsystem.ui.views` package under `resources`), then you can just do

```
Parent view = FXMLLoader.load(Login.class.getResource("Login.fxml"));
```

If you need to troubleshoot further, you can see where the resources were deployed (so where they are found at *runtime*), by looking in the `target/classes` folder.

Comment: But the path isnt the path automatically built by intellij, thank you but i still get the same error, the error started when i added spring boot, can it be something wrong with the dependencies in the pom.xml?

Comment: @GeorgeSilva No, this has nothing to do with the dependencies. I don't use IntelliJ, but I've seen other people indicating that it doesn't suggest the correct resource names under some circumstances. (And it's always a mistake to blindly believe what your IDE suggests anyway.) What is in your `target/classes` folder?

Comment: I checked the target classes and the path is correct, i changed the path by including the fxml file in the same package as Login but i still get the error

Comment: @GeorgeSilva Update the question to show the actual content of `target/classes`

Comment: I did just now added the target/classes

Comment: @GeorgeSilva See update to answer. You have a *folder* called `com.ui.views` under `resources`, not a *package* called `com.ui.views`. Consequently, in the build folder (`target/classes`) you have `com.ui.views` instead of `com/ui/views`.